# Java Soap Request Getting 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

I need to write Java SOAP client code to consume the web service upon the customer request. While i call java client code, i am getting 401 Unauthorized response code. However, when i call from postman, everything is fine. Here is the Java Client Code.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.http.client.AuthCache;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicAuthCache;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

  @SpringBootApplication
 public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

static {
    //disableSslVerification();
}

public static void disableSslVerification() {
    try
    {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
            }
        }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        // Create all-trusting host name verifier
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting host verifier
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}

private final String REALM = "Restricted";
private final String SEPARATOR = ", ";
private final String QUOTE = "\"";
private final String NONCE = Long.toString(new Random().nextLong(), 36);

private String setAuthorizationHeader(String method, String username, String password,String nonce) throws AuthenticationException {



    DigestScheme digestScheme = new DigestScheme();
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
    String digest4 = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(username + ":" + REALM + ":" + password +new Date().getTime());
    String digest2 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(method + ":" + "/");
    params.put("uri","/soap/sp");
        params.put("realm","Restricted");
        params.put("nonce",nonce);
        params.put("nc","01");
        params.put("cnonce","0a458m12");
        params.put("qop","auth");
        params.put("methodname","POST");
        params.put("algorithm","MD5");

    String md5Hex = DigestScheme.createDigest("arbor","arbortt",params);
    String header = DigestScheme.createDigestHeader("arbor",params,md5Hex);
    String value = "Digest " + header;

    return value;
}

public String calculateNonce() {
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd:hh:mm:ss");
    String fmtDate = f.format(d);
    Random rand = new Random(100000);
    Integer randomInt = rand.nextInt();
    return DigestUtils.sha1Hex(fmtDate + randomInt.toString());
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
     System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Users\\devuser\\Desktop\\keystorefile");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
        disableSslVerification();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
       String request = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:com.example.demo.PeakflowSP\">\n" +
            "   <soapenv:Header/>\n" +
            "   <soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "      <urn:getDosAlertSummaries soapenv:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">\n" +
            "         <filter xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"></filter>\n" +
            "         <count xsi:type=\"xsd:unsignedInt\"></count>\n" +
            "      </urn:getDosAlertSummaries>\n" +
            "   </soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    String nonce = calculateNonce();
    headers.add("ETag",nonce);

    headers.add("Authorization",setAuthorizationHeader("getDosAlertSummaries","arbor","arbortt",nonce));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request, headers);




    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("https://10.34.34.71/soap/sp", entity, String.class);

    String str = response.getBody();
    str = str.replace("xsi:type=\"ns1:DosAlertSummaryArray\"","");
    str = str.replace("xsi:type=\"xsd:unsignedInt\"","");
    str = str.replace("xsi:type=\"xsd:string\"","");
    str = str.replace("xsi:type=\"xsd:boolean\"","");
    str = str.replace("xsi:type=\"ns1:DosAlertSummary\"","");
    str = str.replace("xsi:type=\"ns1:AlertDirection\"","");
    str = str.replace("xsi:type=\"xsd:float\"","");
    str = str.replace("xsi:type=\"xsd:dateTime\"","");
    str = str.replace("xsi:type=\"ns1:AlertResource\"","");
    str = str.replace("xsi:type=\"ns1:AlertManagedObject\"","");
    str = str.replace("xsi:type=\"ns1:AlertImportance\"","");
    str = str.replace("xsi:type=\"ns1:Annotation\"","");
    str = str.replace("xsi:type=\"ns1:unitType\"","");

    log.info(response.toString());

    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(str));
    xsr.nextTag();
    xsr.nextTag();
    xsr.nextTag();
    xsr.nextTag();

    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new StAXSource(xsr), new StreamResult(stringWriter));
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(stringWriter.toString());
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DosAlertSummaries.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    DosAlertSummaries loginResult = (DosAlertSummaries) unmarshaller.unmarshal(sr);

}
```

}

Here is request log from program :

```
   Digest username="arbor", realm="Restricted", 
  nonce="d90b71aa44b311113dd392e64e6d9347444d3b40", 
  uri="/soap/sp", qop="auth", algorithm="MD5", nc=01, cnonce="0a458m12", 
  response="297349367d0faa283a6649a004e104d1"
```

Postman request log :

```
    Digest username="arbor", realm="Restricted", 
    nonce="Nf7oZOFzBQA=04e0c7c96bad6b7d2eabe2ec03831f55c13cde0d", 
    uri="/soap/sp", algorithm="MD5", qop=auth, nc=01, cnonce="0a458m12", 
   response="480da02481f50f76a7fbc82a63869e2e"
```

Request xml from postman :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:getDosAlertSummaries xmlns:ns1="urn:com.example.demo.PeakflowSP" 
   soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <filter xsi:type="xsd:string" />
     <count xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">100</count>
  </ns1:getDosAlertSummaries>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When i take the nonce value which postman created instead of calculateing in code, i get 200. Could anyone tell me where i am doing wrong  ? Problem can be nonce value. If it is, how i can calculate nonce value correctly ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to log your requests? The truth is the request you are making from your program and the request you are making from Postman are different. I would make sure all your headers are the same.

Comment: some services return 401s when the request does not have a user agent set.

Comment: @SamOrozco 
 Here is my request log from program : 
 Digest username="arbor", realm="Restricted", nonce="d90b71aa44b311113dd392e64e6d9347444d3b40", 
 uri="/soap/sp", qop="auth", algorithm="MD5", nc=01, cnonce="0a458m12", response="297349367d0faa283a6649a004e104d1"

Postman request log :

Digest username="arbor", realm="Restricted", nonce="Nf7oZOFzBQA=04e0c7c96bad6b7d2eabe2ec03831f55c13cde0d", 
uri="/soap/sp", algorithm="MD5", qop=auth, nc=01, cnonce="0a458m12", response="480da02481f50f76a7fbc82a63869e2e"

Comment: @MCO I set user agent, i didnt work.